# cakephp 3.2 $this->Auth->redirectUrl() always returns "\" on production server - Session

Tags: session, authentication, cakephp-3.0, redirect, production-environment

I created Cakephp 3 app witch has login feature. login feature works perfectly on my local machine. However, On production server when the login credentials are corrcet it redirects me to"\" rather than the URL I specified. I beleive it's problem of Session. I mean for some reason the session is lost at the redirection line.

**The Code:**

*Initilaize method of AppController*

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'authenticate'=>[
                    'Form'=>[
                            'fields'=>[
                                    'username'=>'username',
                                    'password'=>'password'
                            ],
                            'finder' => 'auth',
                    ]
            ],
            'loginAction'=>[
                    'controller'=>'Users',
                    'action'=>'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                    'controller'=> 'Pages',
                    'action'=> 'dashboard'
            ],
    ]);
}
```

*UserController.php:*

```
class UsersController extends AppController {


public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user=$this->Auth->identify();     
        if($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(_('your username or password is incorrect, please try agian'), [
                'key' => 'falseSignIn']);
        }
    }
}
public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

}

*here is my session info using phpinfo();*
[image]

Comment: Can you show me the initialize function of app controller where you have defined loginredirect.

Comment: I added in the main question. Please have a look there

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a hidden textbox and assign the value of $this->Auth->redirectUrl() to it. Then you can retrieve the textbox value from your form, and pass it as an argument to $this->redirect().